# Ultimo registro

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Preciso saber como pegar o último registro armazenado no mongo.

Estou fazendo uma busca, comparando dois IDS, preciso que retorne apenas o último registro.

Tenho as seguintes variáveis:

```
client.name  
client.cpf  
client.endereço
```

Estou fazendo a busca da seguinte forma:

```
Client.findById({$and: [{_id: client.Client.id}, {_id: contact.id}]}, {sort: {cpf: -1 }}, function(err, clients) {
                  console.log("client.id: "+client.Client.id)
                  console.log("post"+post)
                  console.log("imprimir: "+contact.code)
                  console.log("nome"+client.cpf)
                callback();
              });
            },
```

Porém não funciona.

Answer (score 3):

**Nodejs**, se for Mongoose 3.8+, pode utilizar a sintaxe:

```
model.findOne().sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 })
```

Ou

```
model.findOne().sort({ field: -_id })
```

Ou seja, `cpf -1` não parece satisfazer a ordem, utilize um campo "decrementavel" como ID ou datas, já que o CPF não segue uma ordem.

`(...) {sort: {id: -1 }} (...)`

**Exemplo**

```
Client.findById({$and: [{_id: client.Client.id}, {_id: contact.id}]}, {sort: {client.Client.id: -1 }}, function(err, clients) {
     // (...)
},
```

Comment: Ok, boa. Vou apagar os comments então...